# Is there a way to have multiple remote desktops logged in simultaneously with the same account in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, remote-access

My problem is the following: I have an Ubuntu 20.04 installation (it is a VM, actually, but it should not be relevant), and four people need to connect to it, sometimes simultaneously. Moreover, the users should connect to the same account but not interfere with each other (hence not see their pointers or the input of the others). Basically, it should be as it happens with SSH (where multiple logins with the same credentials are possible) but with the GUI.
It's been an afternoon of attempts, some of which are:

1. XRDP: can receive multiple connections but only with different accounts, when I try to log in with the same credentials from two different clients one of them is completely black.
2. VirtualBox Remote Display (of the host machine): can offer multiple connections with the same account but every client sees the same desktop as the others.
3. Anydesk (also with multiple virtual desktops): same as 3.
4. SSH with X11: I haven't been able to find a way to share the entire desktop with multiple devices.

The connection will happen inside a LAN or a VPN so security is not my first concern, every solution is accepted!

**EDIT:**
As user1686 correctly pointed out in the answer, this problem is intrinsically difficult to be solved, as many applications will not work correctly when used with the same user account in multiple concurrent sessions. My final solution was to create four different accounts with root privileges and run vncserver on all of them. I also tried with xrdp but (for unknown reasons) it was incredibly slow. VNC runs smooth, at least with 4 users connected.

Comment: In a nutshell: No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, although it won't work well.

X11-over-SSH supports this – the clients just need a local X server that can run in "windowed" mode. For Linux there is Xephyr (which creates a separate $DISPLAY), for Windows most Xservers have windowed mode as an option. Then, instead of starting individual programs, you start the whole desktop environment by running `gnome-session` or something like that. (But it'll be slow.)

VNC also supports this – because Xvnc acts as an X server on the remote side (i.e. it doesn't merely attach to an existing X server), you could actually run multiple instances of it; e.g. `Xvnc :1` for one user, `Xvnc :2` for another, and so on (each using a different VNC port of course). The same goes for RDP.

But the problem with **all** such methods is that many graphical apps and desktop environments are *not* written with multiple instances in mind. They will fight over configuration files; if one client changes the view mode in Files, it will change for all clients because they all share the same home directory. Other programs save their settings on exit, so the last instance to be closed wins and other changes are discarded. Finally, many desktop environment services run a single instance socket (e.g. $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus); sometimes a program will insist on *only* opening new windows on the 1st client's display, no matter which client tries to run it.

You should really, *really* rethink all parts of this setup. Do the clients actually need to share the same account? (If they're editing files – they really don't.) Do the clients actually need to have a full desktop GUI? (In most cases they really don't.)

Comment: That being said, I'd probably help with trying to make it work out of spite, because I _really_ can't stand "In a nutshell: No" comments.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Before I try one of those solutions I'd like to explain to you why I need this setup, maybe you can help me find a better solution. For a university project me and my colleagues have to make a server hosting some vulnerable services to be attacked (e.g. an old version of Apache with a buffer overflow vulnerability). The server configuration has to bee as much as possible similar to a real one. The "safest" option would be to develop configurations locally and then access one at a time the machine to push it, but multiple accesses will let us work in parallel...

Comment: Right, but that doesn't really explain why you need all connections to use the _same credentials?_ It would be a lot easier to have four different user accounts, all of them having sudo rights. (Aside from that, X11 on a server is highly unusual in the first place, and a full desktop environment even more so – if you wanted something as similar as possible to a real server, you'd be working over SSH...)

Comment: You are right, but we've been told to use Ubuntu Desktop. I think that in a real-world environment it is not common to find multiple accounts with root privileges, each one containing different services, but it is a road that I may take if you think that it can work. Anyway, we will delete any service used during development before delivering it.

Comment: Multiple accounts with _sudo access_ are certainly common – that's pretty much the recommended way to have several coworkers manage the same server, as having each user have their own credentials provides auditability (who did what), makes it easier to change the credentials (if everyone uses the same password, it's hard to know how it got stolen, and it means past employees know your root password too). Credential sharing is usually considered a security problem (sometimes unavoidable but a problem nevertheless).

Comment: That's great! What of the above solutions would you advise to be the fastest to set up with multiple accounts?

Comment: I followed your advice and used VNC with different accounts. Thanks for your patience and your help :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what's currently best supported for multi-user remote desktop on Linux; VNC is certainly a common choice, NX and Xpra and XRDP were other popular options at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today.
I wanted to have several users access in RDP to a same Ubuntu account (let's call it "/home/target").

My approach was to create several accounts (one for each connecting users) then remove their Documents/Downloads/etc. and create symlink to the target's home

```
sudo ln -s /home/target/Documents /home/user1/Documents
```

to have write access on the target dir, I also added

```
sudo adduser user1 target
```

(to add user1 to the target group)
and

```
chmod g+w /home/target
chmod g+w -R /home/target/Documents
```

(to give write permission to the target **group**)

This way all users were able to connect simultaneously (each /home/userX/ containt the temporary session, etc.) and have access to the common/shared directories.